# Different descriptions of the Baumslag-Solitar groups using affine groups

Tags: group-theory, gap

On page 101 of [this paper of Laurent Bartholdi](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/fr-2.1.1/doc/manual.pdf) (which is an online documentation of the [FR package for GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/fr.html) which allows GAP to manipulate groups generated by automata) he gives a different description of the Baumslag-Solitar group

```
gap> A := FRAffineGroup(1,Integers,3);
<self-similar group over [ 1 .. 3 ]>
gap> f := Correspondence(A);
MappingByFunction( ( Integers^[ 2, 2 ] ), <self-similar group over [ 1 .. 3 ]>, 
function( mat ) ... end )
gap> BaumslagSolitar := Group([[2,0],[0,1]]^f,[[1,0],[1,1]]^f);
<self-similar group over [ 1 .. 3 ] with 2 generators>"
```

This description of the Baumslag-Solitar group is quite unusual. How can I relate this definition of Bartholdi with the classical one? I didn't also find anything relevant about the relation between affine groups and Baumslag-Solitar groups. Bartholdi states thatt the group $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\rtimes_2\mathbb{Z}$ is the Baumslag Solitar described by the above GAP procedure. Why? What means the $\rtimes_2$? I have always seen a Baumslag-Solitar group as this $$BS(1,m)=\langle a,b| bab^{-1}=a^m\rangle.$$

Comment: $\rtimes_2$ means that the positive generator of $\mathbf{Z}$ acts by multiplication by $2$. That the canonical homomorphism $BS(1,m)\to \mathbf{Z}[1/m]\rtimes_m\mathbf{Z}$ is an isomorphism is an elementary exercise. (If $|m|,|n|\ge 2$ there is also a canonical homomorphism $BS(m,n)\to \mathbf{Z}[1/mn]\rtimes_{m/n}\mathbf{Z}$, which is surjective but no longer injective.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to prove the statement. I don'y understand the link between $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\rtimes_2\mathbb{Z}$ and Affine groups since Bartholdi mentioned Affine groups in the GAP program above.

Comment: The affine group occurs this way: another representation of $BS(m,n)=\langle t,x,tx^mt^{-1}=x^n$, into the affine group, maps $t$ to $x\mapsto (m/n)x$, and $x$ to $x\mapsto x+1$. It is faithful if and only if $\min(|m|,|n|)=1<\max(|m|,|n|)$.

Answer (score 1):

These Baumslag-Solitar groups BS(1,m) are linear: view a=[1,1;0,1] and b=[m,0;0,1].

Finitely generated linear groups can be represented using finite automata, rather than matrices. Explicit automata are described in

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603032

and they are those that are implemented in GAP.